# Codeacademy--Probably easy to answer

Tags: javascript

I have been learning javascript slowly on codeacademy and I recently did a lesson in which you script your name to bounce around on mouse over. I'd just like to be able to put this code somewhere like as a desktop background or a small .exe that I could send to my wife with a message. Here is the code.

```
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = "My Name";
var letterColors = [red, orange, green];
if(1 < 3) {
    bubbleShape = "circle";
}

else {
    bubbleShape = "square";
}

drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceBubbles();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the specific question?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net maybe?

Comment: @HamZa, no question ... I think OP want's to share his achievement out of excitement :)

Comment: @HamZa I think he wants to know how to show it to his wife

Answer (score 2):

Use Codecademy Codebits to make a project to share with whomever.

Codebits: http://www.codecademy.com/codebits

Answer (score 0):

You could always save it as a plain HTML file.

Open this up in a text editor (like notepad - **not wordpad**), and save it as "myPage.html" or something similar (make sure the extension is .html). If you double-click the file, it should open in your default browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* Your javascript code here */

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```